# Como Recorrer un Array de una Consulta a la bd y Totalizar los Valores Dependiendo del Numero de Factura - php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hola a todos lo que estoy tratando de realizar es recorrer la consulta que me arroja desde la base de datos y mostrar el resultado en una tabla html, pero quiero que por cada numero de factura me totalice y siga recorriendo el array.

asi es como esta

```
N° Factura   Fecha       Producto  Cantidad  ValorUnitario   SubTotal
factura      2021-07-31    1        6          1,500           9,000
factura      2021-07-31    6        10         2,000           20,000
factura      2021-07-31    9        5          3,000           15,000
factura      2021-07-31    5        3          2,000           6,000
dfdfd        2021-08-12    1        15         2,000           30,000
dfdfd        2021-08-12    6        10         2,000           20,000
Total: 100.000,00
```

como debe quedar

```
N° Factura   Fecha       Producto  Cantidad  ValorUnitario   SubTotal
    factura      2021-07-31    1        6          1,500           9,000
    factura      2021-07-31    6        10         2,000           20,000
    factura      2021-07-31    9        5          3,000           15,000
    factura      2021-07-31    5        3          2,000           6,000
SubTotal : 50,000
    dfdfd        2021-08-12    1        15         2,000           30,000
    dfdfd        2021-08-12    6        10         2,000           20,000
SubTotal : 50,000

Total: 100.000,00
```

esto es lo que Intente realizar, colocando un if para comprobar si las facturas son iguales y suma los subtotales

```
    <table width="700px" border="1" >
        <tr>
            <th>N° Factura</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Valor Unitario</th>
            <th>Sub Total</th>
        </tr>
        <?php $total=0; $subtotal=0; 
             while  ($row = $dEntrada->fetch_object()) { 
              //codigo para realizar el total de cada factura
                 if ($row->NroFactura==$row->NroFactura) {
                    $subtotal+=$row->Cantidad * $row->PrecioUnitario;
                 }
                echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$row->NroFactura.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row->Fecha.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row->ProductoId.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row->Cantidad.'</td>
                        <td>'.number_format($row->PrecioUnitario).'</td>
                        <td>'. number_format( $sub=$row->Cantidad * $row->PrecioUnitario).'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td>'.$subtotal.'</td></tr>';
                        $total+=$sub;
             } ?>
             <tr><td colspan="6"><?php echo "Total: ".number_format($total,2,',','.'); ?></td></tr>
    </table>
```

pero esta condición no me funciono porque me suma todo sin tener en cuenta la condición y queda asi

```
N° Factura    Fecha        Producto   Cantidad    ValorUnitario   SubTotal
factura       2021-07-31     1           6          1,500          9,000
subTotal :9000
factura       2021-07-31     6           10         2,000          20,000
subTotal :29000
factura       2021-07-31     9           5          3,000          15,000
subTotal :44000
factura       2021-07-31     5           3          2,000          6,000
subTotal :50000
dfdfd         2021-08-12     1           15         2,000          30,000
subTotal :80000
dfdfd         2021-08-12     6           10         2,000          20,000
subTotal :100000

Total: 100.000,00
```

Comment: Esta condición siempre dará `TRUE`: `if ($row->NroFactura==$row->NroFactura) `

Comment: Hola @David JP gracias por responder como debería hacer para lograr lo que quiero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrias hacerlo asi:

```
$rows=array();
$els= array();

    while  ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){

          $rows[] = $row;
          //contamos la cantidad de resultados por factura
          $els[$row["NroFactura"]]= !isset($els[$row["NroFactura"]]) ? 1 : ++$els[$row["NroFactura"]];
    }
    
$contador=1;
$sub_total=array();
$total = 0;

foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
    //echo $rows[$key]["NroFactura"];

     echo '<tr>
               <td>'.$rows[$key]["NroFactura"].'</td>
               <td>'.$rows[$key]["Fecha"].'</td>
               <td>'.$rows[$key]["ProductoId"].'</td>
               <td>'.$rows[$key]["Cantidad"].'</td>
               <td>'.number_format($rows[$key]["PrecioUnitario"]).'</td>
               <td>'. number_format($rows[$key]["Cantidad"] * $rows[$key]["PrecioUnitario"]).'</td>';

               //verificamos que exista la llave para esta factura
               if(!isset($sub_total[$rows[$key]["NroFactura"]])){
                // creamos la llave y le asignamos la multiplicacions
                $sub_total[$rows[$key]["NroFactura"]] = $rows[$key]["Cantidad"] * $rows[$key]["PrecioUnitario"];
               }else{
                // en caso de que exista se le suma la nueva multiplicacion
                $sub_total[$rows[$key]["NroFactura"]] += $rows[$key]["Cantidad"] * $rows[$key]["PrecioUnitario"];
               }

                // ahora validamos que sea el ultimo elemento de 
                if($els[$rows[$key]["NroFactura"]] == $contador){
                    // imprimimos subtotal
                    echo "</tr><tr><td>subtotal: "  .number_format($sub_total[$rows[$key]["NroFactura"]]) . "</td>";
                    $total +=$sub_total[$rows[$key]["NroFactura"]];
                    // ponemos contador a 0
                    $contador=0;
                }
        // aumentamos contador.
        $contador++;
        // cerramos tr
        echo "</tr>";
 
}
echo "<tfoot><tr><td>total: " . $total ."</td></tr></tfoot>";
```

## nota:

debes hacer un **order by NroFactura,fecha**

otra opcion seria hacerlo directo en la sql
ejemplo:

```
SELECT f.NroFactura,
factura.Fecha,
factura.ProductoId,
factura.Cantidad,
factura.PrecioUnitario,
f.cantidadF,f.subtotal_total
FROM factura,
(SELECT NroFactura,
 COUNT(*) as cantidadF,
 SUM(Cantidad*PrecioUnitario) as subtotal_total
 FROM factura GROUP BY NroFactura) as f
WHERE factura.NroFactura = f.NroFactura
ORDER BY f.NroFactura DESC, factura.Fecha
```

Comment: Hola @Bryro el ciclo del foreach me arroja un ciclo infinito de error y ahora estoy probando la consulta sql

Comment: las dos respuestas funcionan correctamente justo lo que necesitaba muchas gracias